# Replacing specific parts of text in an external file

Tags: python-3.x

and thanks in advance for taking the time to read and potentially answer this question, please keep in mind that I'm very new to python, I've been searching for an answer to this question for a while, I'm trying to take another .py file in this case called "strings.py" and replace some of the lines with new numbers (this is just a test for what I want to do later.) So my example strings.py file contains

```
1
2
3
```

I want to write a piece of code in another .py file calle rewrite.py that replaces the number 2 with the number 5, so that after I run rewrite.py if I open strings.py it reads

```
1
5
3
```

Hopefully this makes sense, I've tried a lot of different things here and looked at a lot of posts but most are around 10 years old and I'm not good enough at python to translate what they have done and make it work in 3.X, nothing I've tried has come remotely close so far so I haven't included any code. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: you can read each line of your file using `readlines()` method and then iterate over every line to check if its value is what you want and replace it.

Comment: Could you elaborate on thsi please @BijayRegmi? I can see that if I use `readlines()` and then print it I get a list, but how would I change the values in the file with that? Sorry if this is obvious, I'm very new to python.

Comment: nice, you could figure out how to read file lines as a list, now you can iterate over list items and replace them using list comprehension in python like `new_lines = [ 5 if x == 2 for x in your_list]` and then you can use `file.writelines(new_lines)` to write these lines into your file.

Comment: Thanks for the help I've managed to make this work with a couple of workarounds, cheers!